# Why can't I specialize an NSSet in Swift?

Tags: swift

So as of xcode 7 the foundation collections are generics which is great so you can do this in ObjC:

```
NSSet<NSString *> *foo = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:@[]];
```

But if you try to specialize the NSSet in Swift:

```
let foo:NSSet<String> = NSSet(array: [])
```

You get this: `Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSSet'`

Now, I know Swift has a `Set` class as well that is generic and bridges to `NSSet`, but I am doing this for `NSManagedObject` subclasses so I need to support `NSOrderedSet` as well and there is no ordered set in Swift yet.

My question is, is this intentional or is this an oversight? Is there any reason `NSSet` wouldn't be exposed as a generic class in Swift but would be in ObjC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID61) says:

> All `NSSet` objects can be bridged to Swift sets, so the Swift compiler replaces the `NSSet` class with `Set<AnyObject>` when it imports Objective-C APIs.

So, as matt already said with other words in his answer, `NSSet` inside the Swift language is identical to `Set<AnyObject>`, and *is not* the same thing as `NSSet` in the current version of Objective-C language, even if they have the same name.

Continuing to cite the documentation:

> You can also create an `NSSet` object directly from a Swift array literal, following the same bridging rules outlined above. When you explicitly type a constant or variable as an `NSSet` object and assign it an array literal, Swift creates an `NSSet` object instead of a Swift set.

In other words, it creates an object of type `Set<AnyObject>`, and this is the reason of the error given by the Swift compiler (`NSSet` is not generic since it correspond to the generic `NSSet` in Object-C, but *already instantiated* on the type `AnyObject`).

What you can do is to write something like:

```
let foo = NSSet(array: ["one", "two", "three"])

// foo has now the type NSSet<AnyObject>, which corresponds to Set<AnyObject>

let bar = foo as! Set<String>

// bar has now the type Set<String>, which has no correspondent as NSSet<...> in Swift
```